# SyntaxError: Expected an indented block exception thrown

Tags: python

[image]

I have write this code to collect all data from twitter for cities like London. I have tried to write a code using python and it's give me this error on the line:

`def process_or_store(tweet):
 print(json.dumps(tweet)`

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: You need to indent the line by 4 spaces like you have done in every other method

Comment: Please post your actual code, not pictures of your code, along with the specific error, the behaviour you expected, what happened instead, etc. See [ask]

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please check out [ask]. Please do not post links to code, especially links to *images* of code. Post your code in the question itself as formatted text.

Comment: You should indent your code, and you're missing a closing bracket `)`

Comment: expected an indented block in this statemetment that i have wrote in my topic ..

Comment: @constantinosgeorgiou no, again, please see [ask]. You need to provide a [mcve]. Do *not post images of code*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a tabulator or spaces in front of this line (depends on what you used in the above lines), so it looks like:

```
def process_or_store(tweet):
    print(json.dumps(tweet))
```

Remind, that python does not use `{}` to determine where a function starts and ends. A function must be in one **indentation level** instead.
You also forgot to close brackets at `print()`.
Take the above definition, its syntax is correct.
Be aware of mixing up tabs and spaces (some editors manage this automatically, but if not, this can lead to errors that are not obvious)

Answer (score 0):

Update:

```
def process_or_store(tweet):
print(json.dumps(tweet)
```

To be:

```
def process_or_store(tweet):
    print(json.dumps(tweet))
```

and then delete your question

Comment: its ok thank for the answer sorry for that i am a new in the forum and python

Comment: i have another issue i have wrote the solution that you told me put before run the python he  gave me the error  def proccess_or_(tweet):  undented does not match any outer indentation level  what does the error mean?

Comment: sorry about the photo of the code is the last time that i done  this, he give this new syntax error i dont know why i have try to rewrite the code put the syntax error is here